# Export Yahoo Pipe as CSV?

Tags: csv, yahoo-pipes

I see references to Get As CSV once I am done with a Yahoo Pipe from other video sources but the link seems not to exist any longer under more options?

Is there an additional step I am meant to take to get this working?

And if not, how do I get my Pipe to export as CSV so that I can import it into another desktop app?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

1. Go to the page of your pipe, for example: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=99240a186b2099bc028d7d7e37c1f224
2. Click on the **Get as RSS** link, for example: 
   http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=99240a186b2099bc028d7d7e37c1f224&_render=rss
3. Edit the URL, change the `render=rss` to `render=csv`, for example: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=99240a186b2099bc028d7d7e37c1f224&_render=csv